# How to install Typescript 2.2 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have installed below but its not showing in typescript version dropdown
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.TypeScript22forVisualStudio2015

[image]

Comment: That plugin is for Visual Studio 2015, you cannot install it on 2019.

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, I have tried  "Get Tools and Features" under the Tools menu to install version 2.2 but that version is not showing under the individual components tab. do you have any idea?